# Compilation of java program leads to FileNotFound error in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I built my java program using maven internally from eclipse and I came across the following error:

```
   Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\BennyJ\workspace\Tom\common\target\classes (Access is denied)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:106)
at      org.codehaus.plexus.util.io.FileInputStreamFacade.getInputStream(FileInputStreamFacade.java:39)
at org.codehaus.plexus.util.FileUtils.copyStreamToFile(FileUtils.java:1106)
at org.codehaus.plexus.util.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:1013)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.war.packaging.AbstractWarPackagingTask.copyFile(AbstractWarPackagingTask.java:293)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.war.packaging.AbstractWarPackagingTask$1.registered(AbstractWarPackagingTask.java:150)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.war.util.WebappStructure.registerFile(WebappStructure.java:211)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.war.packaging.AbstractWarPackagingTask.copyFile(AbstractWarPackagingTask.java:145)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.war.packaging.ArtifactsPackagingTask.performPackaging(ArtifactsPackagingTask.java:106)
... 27 more
```

As an update, running eclipse as administrator solved the issue. However, now it is giving a new error as follows:

```
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project client: Compilation failure
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilationFailureException: Compilation failure
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:656)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more`
```

What could be causing this?

Comment: Maybe you need to run Eclipse as administrator?

Comment: You were absolutley right running eclipse as administrator solved the issue However now it is giving a new error as follows:

Comment: How about moving your workspace out of your user directory to something like c:\workspace\GBSTFO. That way you can run eclipse as the current user.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your current user has the necessary permissions to access the file. If they do, make sure that nothing else (other threads, programs, or users) has a lock on the necessary file.